# App Transport Security verbose is not working ios 14.1

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, ios14, cfnetwork

I configure CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS in edit my schema App set the level to 3. and added code snippet to my `AppDelegate` function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` `setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 1)` compile the app and I don't have log CFNetwork diagnostics log file created in my console in the simulator console or folder

Comment: you should not use both things together. either use CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS in edit scheme or AppDelegate function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could figure out why `CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS`is not working with XCode 12.1. I found this Github project to profile web request from an actual device
just add this snippet code for AppDelegate

```
// AppDelegate
import netfox
NFX.sharedInstance().start() // in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

https://github.com/kasketis/netfox/blob/master/README.md